# Understanding TCP RST in Wireshark

Tags: tcp, wireshark, iis-8.5, tcp-rst

I need help to understand the red and black errors in Wireshark (see the attached screenshot). Those errors are produced when I try to access a large PDF file hosted in a static folder on IIS.

My knowledge of TCP protocols is very limit. Any help is really appreciated!

[image]

Comment: As TCP protocol defines RST as a valid building block, it is not "error" by default. What exactly happened when you accessed the PDF file on IIS? Typical errors should be at HTTP level, and reading at TCP level right now is inappropriate.

Comment: I was trying to identify if this is a firewall issue. This online PDF could be accessed through http://localhost/pdffile, but not http://<public IP address>/pdffile

Comment: Install Wireshark on both the browser side and server side. Then capture packets at the same time and reproduce the issue. By analyzing both sides, you can decide if a certain packet (from the firewall for instance) breaks your access to this PDF.

Comment: A good advice. Thank you!